# OpenLayers map not displaying - asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, openlayers-3

I am currently trying to build a website using ASP.NET. On one of my pages, I need to display a map that will have overlays and fills on it. However, I cannot get the map to display on my .aspx files. I am coding the site using the free version Visual Studio 2017 RC and using the built in IIS debugger to preview the site as I build it. I am using OpenLayers to make my map. I've managed to get the map to display in an empty HTML document, but using the same map code in my .aspx file it will not display.

[What the Map.aspx file results in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdEZF.png)
 *The windows logo is just a temp until i make mine*

Here is the code in my Map.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Map.aspx.cs" Inherits="pages_map_Map" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Civil Wars: Age of Rebellion</title>
    <link href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../css/Map.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<link href="../css/Login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <!--Start Navbar-->
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="../Home.aspx" ><img id="logo" alt="Civil Wars: Age of Rebellion" src="../../images/tempLogo.png" height="30" />Civil Wars: Age of Rebellion</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="home" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Home.aspx">Home</asp:LinkButton>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Places<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Training Center</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Market<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Exchange</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="battles" runat="server" PostBackUrl="#">Battles</asp:LinkButton>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Community<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">My Country</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Military Unit</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Newspaper</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Party</a></li>
                                    <li class="active"><a href="Map.aspx">World Map</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:Button ID="logOut" runat="server" Text="Logout" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End Navbar-->
        </div>
        <!--Start Content-->
        <div id="main" class="container center-page">
            <h1>Map</h1>
            <hr />
            <!--Start Map-->
            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target = 'map',
                    maxResolution: 1000,
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    view: [
                        new ol.View({
                            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                            zoom: 4
                        })
                    ]
                });
            </script>
            <!--End Map-->
        </div>
        <!--End Content-->
        <!--- Footer  -->
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <p class="pull-right"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
                <p>&copy; 2017 Civil Wars Studio &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="../Home.aspx">Home</a> &middot; <a href="#">Changelog</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms of Service</a> &middot; <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Contact</a></p>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!--- Footer -->
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to skip right to where the map div and js is:

```
<!--Start Content-->
        <div id="main" class="container center-page">
            <h1>Map</h1>
            <hr />
            <!--Start Map-->
            <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map = new ol.Map({
                    target = 'map',
                    maxResolution: 1000,
                    layers: [
                        new ol.layer.Tile({
                            source: new ol.source.OSM()
                        })
                    ],
                    view: [
                        new ol.View({
                            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                            zoom: 4
                        })
                    ]
                });
            </script>
            <!--End Map-->
        </div>
        <!--End Content-->
```

Here is the code in my Map.css file:

```
#navbar {
    height: 70px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(../../images/tempBackground.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
hr {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0 solid;
}
#form1 {
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#home {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.dropdown {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#battles {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#logOut {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#main {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    height: 60% inherit;
    width: 75%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any help as to why my OpenLayers map will not display will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This is also one of my first asp.net projects so any suggestions or warnings to make this better would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: change target: 'map'

Comment: follow this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-icon.html

Comment: I have followed the openlayer examples, and retried the one you linked as well. However, this still had no affect towards my problem.

Comment: could you update js section and show if there is an error in console

Comment: actually your fix did work thanks! I had all my js at the bottom of the body tags for performance, but wasn't thinking that i needed to references the ol.js openlayer script in the header, although it needed to be references BEFORE i tried to initialized the map. After moving the script to the header, everything worked, thanks for the help!!